# Introducing delay in a java program

Tags: java

I am calling a .exe file from my java code using :

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process p=null;
p=r.exec("ABCD.exe");
```

I want the program to wait till the exe completes its job .(This is actually server side code...control passes to Client side after this).The problem now is that UI on client side is populated before the .exe on server side can form the required components.Hence UI formed does not have the correct files.
I have tried the normal p.waitfor() thing but it doesn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is built-in, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234138#234138

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" isn't very clear. What happens, exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  Pink unicorns come out of your CD-ROM drive?

Comment: @Mark: You owe me a new keyboard.

Comment: @Mark: You owe me a new CD-ROM drive.

Comment: @Mark: You owe me a new unicorn. (It could be yellow though, I am bored of pink.)

Comment: @all:- doesnt seem to work means that the print command that I have after this line takes a while to show (probably the time it takes for process to finish) but the UI gets loaded before the files are formed by the exe.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you want to call [Process.waitFor()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) in your main thread, as you allude to.

However, dealing with Processes is not exactly fire-and-forget, because, *as referenced by the class javadocs*, you likely need to be reading the process' output.  If you don't do this (which in this case will require a separate thread) then in many instances you'll have an effective deadlock - your Java app is waiting for the process to finish, but the process is trying to write output to a full buffer and thus waiting for the Java app to read its output.

If you gave more information about how "it didn't work", that would help with the diagnosis too.

---

Edit: on a completely separate point, there's no purpose in initialising `p` to null and then immediately reassigning it.  Your second line would be clearer and less confusing as `Process p = r.exec("ABCD.exe");`.

Comment: Points for noting the chicken and egg problem. This is too often overlooked in those cases. Also see this blog article: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: Nice link - I'll use it in future as further reading for questions like this.

Comment: and btw -> exit value is returning a 0 and documentation says that is normal termination

Comment: If you *get* a return value back, then the process returned, and ostensibly executed correectly.  So *please*, expand on how it "didn't work", as all the signs suggest it did?

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain that.The problem is not getting it to work correctly (output files are formed correctly) but thing is that I want to ensure the proper order.I try to call the server through a  RPC from the client side .In the server side code I call the exe that creates my output files .Now I put a few print statements and see that the UI part of the client code is executing before the .exe file on server side can finish its job .I want to somehow ensure that the UI part in client code( which is right after the server side call) executes only after the .exe finishes its work.

Comment: Well, `p.waitFor()` will cause the calling thread to block until the process has returned, so *if* the UI-spawning logic is right after the server side call, and is only called by the same thread, it won't happen until the exe has exited.

Comment: Ok....I made a change and put the UI code in the onSuccess part of the RPC call[and also kept the p.waitfor () part in server side] .Now it is loading the files for the first time correctly but if clear the UI and  repeat the action again( ie. press button in UI to generate same files again ) the output files do not show up in the UI.[The .exe file creates video files and the UI just shows the player toolbar ].I am confused as to why something that works correctly for first time doesnt show up correctly next time?
P.S. files are still created correctly in the output folder.

Comment: I allways read 'server side' and 'client side'. But we just see 2 lines of code, which don't deal with client/server issues. Is it just me, lacking information? 'It's loading the files ...' uh, really?